# Error using inline Embedded Login

Tags: visualforce, community, authentication, login, embedded

I have a SFDC Community, which has its own Visualforce login page. I have another application running in a cloud host, and I'm trying to use embedded login to authenticate in my community in this external application.

I've followed the steps from this doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_login_all_steps.htm, and when using popup mode, it opens my Visualforce page in a new window and the login works just fine.

The problem is that I'm trying to use inline mode, and while the login form shows up, I can't login with any user, always receiving the message *We can't log you in. Make sure your username and password are correct.*
Looking at the user login information, there's no failed attempt, so I believe it's failing before even trying to check the users credentials.

[image: We can't log you in. Make sure your username and password are correct.]

I've setup a connected app and an auth provider (Salesforce), but still can't figure out what is missing. Can anyone please help with this?

Thanks.